# Can't see my session array list after reloading the page

Tags: php, session

I have a php session array and ajax request to add captured data to a div via java script. All works fine except when I refresh the page the data disappears until I add the next item all shows up again. How can I fix this issue?

file 1 (test.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var myname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else
    {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("POST", "test2.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("firstname="+myname);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Enter Your Name</h1>
<input id="firstname"> </input>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"> Add Item </button>
<div  id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

file 2 (test2.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

$myitems = array();
if (!isset($_SESSION['item'])) $_SESSION['item']=$myitems;
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $data = $_POST['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['item'][] = $data;
}

//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($_SESSION);
//echo '</pre>';

foreach ($_SESSION['item'] as $key=>$value){
echo "<h2>".$value."</h2>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the beginning of every page you need the session array on?

Comment: Well atleast I don't have any super powers to solve your question unless and until you provide some code

Comment: People have wisdom here ,they are not wizard. Come on man , share your code and describe your problem precisely.

Comment: just added the code please see if you can help. There is session_start() at the beginning of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your page test1.php.. When you are refreshing the page the appended data to the div element will be lost. That is expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var myname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else
    {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("POST", "test2.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("firstname="+myname);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Enter Your Name</h1>
<input id="firstname"> </input>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"> Add Item </button>
<div  id="myDiv">
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['item'])){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION['item']);
echo "</pre>";
}
?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks shanavascet this really worked.

Comment: @user2404696 hope you understood what went wrong with your code and logic :)

Answer (score 0):

> All works fine except when I refresh the page the data disappears until I add the next item all shows up again.

And why are you expecting a different behavior? Even if you might already *have* items in your session – you are not *outputting* them anywhere in your test.php, so how do you expect to see them there?

Add code to that file that loops over items in the session and output the HTML code you want inside your div.

---

Btw., this is totally superfluous,

```
$myitems = array();
if (!isset($_SESSION['item'])) $_SESSION['item']=$myitems;
```

if a session is started, $_SESSION is an array already. And PHP does not care if you initialize “under-arrays” before assigning values to them. So even with a totally empty session,

```
$_SESSION['item'][] = $data;
```

without any further initialization of `$_SESSION['item']` will work just fine without any complaints from PHP.